Diagonal metric with induced metric being diagonal as well
A nondegenerate cyclic surface in $\Bbb L^3$ (Lorentz-Minkowski space) with constant (Gaussian curvature) $K \ne 0$ is a surface of revolution. Take a surface of revolution $S\subset \Bbb L^3$ with some constant $1<K<2$ and $p_0=(0,0,0)$ and $p_1=(1,1,1)$ elements of $S$. Does there exist a diagonal metric on $\Bbb L^3$ in which the induced metric on $S$ is diagonal as well?
